# Python subprocess - how to redirect only input

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I am trying to use subprocess32 for running a process in a new console, send some input to it and wait for the process to finish.

```
p = subprocess32.Popen("test.exe", creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, stdin=subprocess32.PIPE)
p.communicate(input="input_file.txt")
```

The problem is that when I redirect stdin to pipe I don't see any output in the new console. Without redirecting to pipe I cannot send my input to the command. 
Is there any way to open a process in new console which would accept my input and at the same time show all output?

Comment: Probably the process uses full buffering for its output after detecting that its stdin is a pipe. Does it have an option to disable output buffering, like Python's `-i` command-line option that forces interactive mode?

Comment: Thanks for reply. No it does not. It simply asks for input and output file name and then starts the simulation. The output during a simulation can be quite long as it writes a line every second or so and can run for hours.  If I understand correctly you think that the problem is in my .exe process?

Comment: Unless this is run from another thread, then `communicate` is blocking the main thread. If the main program doesn't have to continue accepting input in the current console, you could just use that instead of a new console, and write directly to the input buffer instead of using a pipe. You can create a new console screen buffer for its output, and after it exits switch back to the original screen. That way the user doesn't lose context.

Comment: Main program needs to wait for the subprocess to finish. My main function creates an external subprocess multiple times and compiles the results after each run of the subprocess. Ideally I would like to call this function from a threadpool (using python Thread) but even when I try calling this function directly without any multithreading I am still experiencing the same problem.